# Cluster-issuer secret wont replicate with multiple ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I was under the impression that the main point of cluster-issuer is that its namespaced and doesn't have to be recreated across different resources, in general there could be one main cluster-issuer that will manage all ingresses across the cluster.

From what I am seeing the cluster-issuer can only create one secret and if its in use by one ingress the second wont wont be created properly cause its already taken.

Is there anyway to create one cluster-issuer to manage all ingresses across the cluster?

Code included below

#### Cluster-issuer.yaml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-grafana
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: foo@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-grafana
    solvers:
    - selector:
        dnsZones:
          - "foo.com"
      dns01:
        route53:
          region: eu-central-1
          hostedZoneID: foo
          accessKeyID: foo
          secretAccessKeySecretRef:
            name: aws-route53-creds
            key: password.txt
```

#### Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: loki
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-grafana
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size:  "125m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - grafana.foo.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-grafana # < cert-manager will store the created certificate in this secret.
  rules:
  - host: grafana.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: loki-grafana
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Harsh Manvar while I do appreciate your anwser I found something that is a better suit for my needs.

[Cert-manager documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/syncing-secrets-across-namespaces/) contains multiple options to sync secrets across namespaces

The one I chose was [reflector](https://github.com/emberstack/kubernetes-reflector). The steps to install are included in the documentation but just for the sake of service i'll post here aswell

###### Requirements: [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/)

##### Installation:

```
helm repo add emberstack https://emberstack.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install reflector emberstack/reflector
```

#### Setup:

Add the following annotation to your secret `reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-allowed: "true"`, it should look like the following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: source-secret
 annotations:
   reflector.v1.k8s.emberstack.com/reflection-allowed: "true"
```

Done! Your secret should be replicated within all namespaces. For multiple ingress configurations within the same namespace you could edit your ingress.yaml like this

##### Ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: jenkins
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-global
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size:  "125m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - jenkins.foo.com
    - nginx.foo.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-global # < cert-manager will store the created certificate in this secret.
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: jenkins
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: nginx.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: great, answer thought you might looking for multi ingress answer in namespace as not mentioned anywhere in question about cloning secret across namespace else would have recommended better option. Great thanks for sharing..!

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend creating the **wildcard** **certificate** using **issuer/clusterissuer**.

So you will be having the **single secret** with **wildcard** **cert** so you can use that across all ingress.

As you are already using **DNS** verification it will work well, as **wildcard** not supports the **HTTP**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: test123@gmail.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - selector:
        dnsZones:
          - "devops.example.in"
      dns01:
        route53:
          region: us-east-1
          hostedZoneID: Z0152EXAMPLE
          accessKeyID: AKIA5EXAMPLE
          secretAccessKeySecretRef:
            name: route53-secret
            key: secret-access-key
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: le-crt
spec:
  secretName: tls-secret
  issuerRef: 
    kind: Issuer
    name: letsencrypt-prod
  commonName: "*.devops.example.in"
  dnsNames:
    - "*.devops.example.in"
```

Read my full article : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/wild-card-certificate-using-cert-manager-in-kubernetes-3406b042d5a2

**Ingress** & **secret** example

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: dns01
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-dns01-provider: route53
  name: ingress-resource-tls
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "hello.devops.example.in"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - "hello.devops.example.in"
    secretName: tls-secret
```